# Textbox erase data after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, postback

I have a problem with a textbox tha doesn't preserve the data on postback, In my code I have the asp.cs Event btnGuardar button is doing insert them through a stored procedure and doing postback and the problem here is that when you postback the other fields in which data is maintained except put the texbox title news, I don't understand is that in my pc working locally using windows pro 8.1 and the latest version of iis, but this bug that does not save me the value of texbox it happens in windows server 2012 and this happens to me in several texbox other pages in the system I'm doing.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AltaEvento.aspx.cs" Inherits="Apartados_Administrar_Eventos_AltaEvento" EnableViewState="true" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" Assembly="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <style>
        .pickerEventosAdmin
        {
            width: 600px;
        }

    </style>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="other-box yellow-box ui-corner-all">
        <div class="cont tooltip ui-corner-all"
            title="Para mayor informaci&oacute;n: - Comun&iacute;quese con el administrador - Consulte la documentaci&oacute;n del m&oacute;dulo">
            <h3>Alta y Edici&oacute;n de eventos</h3>
            <p>
                Genere nuevos eventos y edite anteriores. Un evento puede contener im&aacute;genes, v&iacute;deos, y documentos.
            </p>
            <p>
                Puede agregar las im&aacute;genes, v&iacute;deos, y documentos despu&eacute;s de que guarde el evento.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
   <%-- <h1><span style="color:red; font-size:20px"> Se está trabajando con esta pantalla. Aún no puede dar de alta eventos</span></h1><br />--%>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all form-container">
        <div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header">Formulario de creaci&oacute;n y edici&oacute;n de eventos</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">
            <ul class="form-ul">     
                <li>
                    <label runat="server" for="<%=txtTituloEvento.ClientID%>">* Titulo del evento:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox  ID="txtTituloEvento" runat="server" CssClass="text  large"></asp:TextBox>
                </li>
                <li class="clearfix"></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="<%=Descripcion.ClientID%>">* Informaci&oacute;n del evento:</label>
                    <cc:HtmlEditor ID="Descripcion" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="750px"
                        ToggleMode="None" BackColor="White" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke"
                        BorderStyle="Solid" ButtonMouseOverColor="193, 210, 238"
                        DialogBackColor="GhostWhite" DialogBorderColor="Black"
                        DialogButtonBarColor="SlateGray" DialogForeColor="Black"
                        DialogHeadingColor="208, 208, 208" DialogHeadingTextColor="127, 157, 185"
                        DialogSelectedTabColor="127, 157, 185" DialogSelectedTabTextColor="White"
                        DialogTableColor="238, 238, 238" DialogUnselectedTabColor="208, 208, 208"
                        EditorBackColor="248, 248, 248" EditorBorderColor="217, 217, 217"
                        EditorInnerBorderColor="GradientInactiveCaption"
                        NoToolstripBackgroundImage="True" TabBackColor="208, 208, 208"
                        ToolbarColor="208, 208, 208"
                        Toolbars="Bold,Italic,Underline:Left,Center,Right,Justify|OrderedList,BulletedList|Subscript,Superscript,Link" />
                </li>
                <li class="clearfix"></li>
                <li>
                    <br />


                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublicar" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" /> Publicar

                     <%--   <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkPublicar" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                        </Triggers>--%>

                </li>
                <li class="clearfix"></li>                                
                <li>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Guardar" CssClass="submitBtn" OnClick="btnGuardar_Click" />
                    <br /><br />
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
```

and the code behind aspx.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public partial class Apartados_Administrar_Eventos_AltaEvento : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected int IdEvento = 0;
        protected string _fechasEvento = "";
        protected string _fechaNuevaEvento = "";

    private void CargaFechasEvento( int eventoId)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Conn = conexionAdmin.Conecta())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdSelFechas = new SqlCommand("SelEventoByID", Conn))
                {
                    cmdSelFechas.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdSelFechas.Parameters.Add("@IDEVENTO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventoId;
                    Conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader drEventos = cmdSelFechas.ExecuteReader();

                    if (drEventos.Read())
                    {
                       _fechasEvento = drEventos["Fecha_Evento"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)drEventos["Fecha_Evento"];
                    }
                    drEventos.Close();
                    Conn.Close();
                    Conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdStatusEvento(int IDNoticia, int Status, string idUser = "")
        {
            Guid userId = new Guid();
            if (idUser != "") { userId = new Guid(idUser); } // Conversion de string to Guid(el formato del UserId del Membership)
            using (SqlConnection Conn = conexionAdmin.Conecta())
            {
                using (SqlCommand CmdUpdStatusNoticia = new SqlCommand("UpStatusEvento", Conn))
                {
                    CmdUpdStatusNoticia.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    CmdUpdStatusNoticia.Parameters.Add("@IDNOTICIA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IDNoticia;

                    CmdUpdStatusNoticia.Parameters.Add("@STATUS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Status;

                    if (idUser != "")
                    {
                        userId = new Guid(idUser);
                        CmdUpdStatusNoticia.Parameters.Add("@USERID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = userId;
                    }
                    Conn.Open();
                    CmdUpdStatusNoticia.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Conn.Close();
                    Conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

            //No shows me the ID of the textbox does not display asp.net control and I value the value entered at the texbox
            //Response.Write(txtTituloEvento.Text);
            //Response.End();
                if (txtTituloEvento.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                    lblMensaje.Text = Alertas.alertaError("", "El t&iacute;tulo del evento es obligatorio");
                    return;
                }
                if (Descripcion.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                    lblMensaje.Text = Alertas.alertaError("", "La descripci&oacute;n del evento es obligatoria");
                    return;
                }

              if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtTituloEvento.Text, Utilidades.validaTextoGeneral))
                {
                    lblMensaje.Text = Alertas.alertaError("", "La Título del evento no puede contener caracteres especiales.");
                    return;
                }

                string comando = "InsEvento";
                if (IdEvento != 0)
                {
                    comando = "UpdEvento";
                }
                using (SqlConnection Conn = conexionAdmin.Conecta())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmdInsEvento = new SqlCommand(comando, Conn))
                    {
                        cmdInsEvento.Connection = Conn;
                        string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; // Usuario logueado
                        MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(user);
                        string idUser = u.ProviderUserKey.ToString(); // Se obtiene el id del usuario pero en formato string
                        Guid userId = new Guid(idUser); // Se convierte a GUID el idUser

                        cmdInsEvento.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add("@TITULO", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtTituloEvento.Text.Trim();
                        cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add("@CONTENIDO", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Descripcion.Text.Trim();
                        cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add("@PUBLICAR", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkPublicar.Checked;
                        if (chkPublicar.Checked == true)
                        {
                            cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add("@USERID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = userId;
                        }
                        SqlParameter prmIdEvento = new SqlParameter("@IDEVENTO", SqlDbType.Int);
                        if (IdEvento != 0)
                        {
                            // update
                            cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add("@IDEVENTO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdEvento;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // insert parametro de salida

                            prmIdEvento.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            cmdInsEvento.Parameters.Add(prmIdEvento);
                        }
                        Conn.Open();
                        cmdInsEvento.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Conn.Close();
                        if (IdEvento == 0)
                        {
                            IdEvento = Convert.ToInt32(prmIdEvento.Value);
                            Response.Redirect("AltaEvento.aspx?Key=" + IdEvento);
                        }
                        lblMensaje.Text = Alertas.alertaExito("", "El evento se actualiz&oacute; correctamente");
                    } /
                }

        } 

        protected void btnVolver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Comment: [this should help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) (I think you have to persist the data yourself and reload it, when i get home I can take a look at an old project, hope this helps)

Comment: I would say either store the value in a session or populate the value in a ASP:HiddenField then in the Page_Load method put the value back in the textbox. Inside Page_Load use If(Page.IsPostback).

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you save your Textbox.text value inside a session variable and rebind it on page load. Check [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/keep-maintain-password-textbox-value.html) for a similar issue.